# gdb interactive console: looking available listings for shared libraries

Tags: c++, linux, gdb

I need to debug a C++ application (compiled with g++-4.5) with gdb on interactive console. I know very little about it, except the start, list and bt commands. I'm not asking for a tutorial about it, as I've found plenty with my old friend google. I just need a little bit help with something I cannot find in the help or references.

The C++ application is a UnitTest++ runner, that links several shared libraries. All these libraries have been built with the appropiate flags for debug information (-ggdb -O0) and I just need a way to set a breakpoint at a certain source file of one of the shared libraries. I'm not sure how I am supposed to navigate to that listing and set the breakpoints

Any gdb guru still out there wanting to lend a hand?

Comment: If you have the source code you can always break using: b /usr/local/lib/boost_1_50_0/boost/iostreams/detail/streambuf/indirect_streambuf.hpp:299

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set breakpoint use `break` command in gdb. You can use the alias `b` also.

Example if you want to break at line 61 in `file.cpp`

`(gdb) b file.cpp:61`

OR

`(gdb) b "file.cpp":61`

If you want to break at a method in a class, type the class name at the gdb prompt and press tab, it will show you all the methods in the class, you can then set breakpoint like this.

Example a method `display()` in `class Foo`

`(gdb) b Foo::display()`

If you want a more interacive/GUI mode then use [Data Display Debugger(DDD)](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) or go for [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/)

To see the status of shared libraries loaded, use `info shared`